# Force the app to stay in portrait mode despite another app's hack

Tags: android, portrait, screen-rotation

Although I force my app to stay in portrait mode `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, but if I use app like Rotation Locker https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker&hl=en and change the mode to Auto-rotate then it bypasses my app setting. 
Any idea how to prevent this? Cheers.

Comment: You can explicitly call this function "setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)" in your code  where you want to keep portrait mode.

Comment: But still i believe if you mention android:screenOrientation="portrait" in your manifest so no app can change its mode to landscape.

Comment: Yes I did put that in the manifest for every activity but that app can make mine rotate. You can try yourself if don't trust me :)

Comment: Actually i tried it first & then i posted my comment. Can you post your manifest? setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) call it in your oncreate.